# go mod tidy duplicates path for importing local package, go.mod replace is "./b" but path to module is reading github.com/x/y/src/a/b/src/a/b/go.mod

Tags: go, import, module

I have local 2 packages that I need to import, that are at different levels within root a

Note: a the root folder name and the file name - a/a.go

src structure is:

```
--src
    --a/
           a.go
           go.mod
           --b/
                 b.go
                 go.mod
```

**I need to import package b into package a**

```
github.com/x/y/src/a/a.go
github.com/x/y/src/a/b/b.go
```

a is a package that uses other packages that i've written, like custom logging tools etc

a.go:

```
package A

import (
    b "github.com/x/y/src/a/b"
```

When I run:

```
go mod tidy
```

I get error:

```
go: github.com/x/y/src/a/a@v0.0.0 requires
github.com/x/y/src/a/b@v0.0.0: reading github.com/x/y/src/a/b/src/a/b/go.mod 
at revision src/a/b/v0.0.0: unknown revision src/a/b/v0.0.0
```

**Why is src/a/b being duplicated in the path it's reading from?!?!?!**

Here's a's go.mod file, it's at the root directory and I need to import packages in folders one level down, so b is ./b/b.go and a is ./a.go :

```
module A

go 1.13

replace (
    github.com/x/y/src/a/b => ./b // look inside folder b for b.go from path where a is located
)

require (
    github.com/x/y/src/a/b v0.0.0
)
```

b's go.mod:

```
module a/b

go 1.13

require golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210124154548-22da62e12c0c
```

**Can someone tell be why go mod tidy is duplicating the path to b:**

```
github.com/x/y/src/a/b/src/a/b/go.mod
```

**It should be:**

```
github.com/x/y/src/a/b/go.mod
```

Comment: Because module B's go.mod is wrong. `module a/b` should be `module github.com/x/y/src/a/b`, because that's the module path.

Comment: @Adrian, is module A is also wrong then?  module A --> github.com/x/y/src/a

Comment: Also note that the `replace` directive has no effect when not building a `main` package from within module a.

Comment: @Adrian i'm still getting the duplicated path issue despite implementing what you said

Comment: @SuperSecretAndHiddenFromWork yes, module a should have `module github.com/x/y/src/a`

Comment: Probably you should not make several modules at all?

Comment: Sadly not up to me to set the folder structure